# Regular expression to find string with iterating letters on the end

Tags: python, regex, string, loops, iterator

Can someone help me with this kind of regular expression matching?

For example, I'm searching through list containing different strings with a letter iterating at the end of the string:

- MonsterA
- MonsterB
- MonsterC
- HeroA
- HeroB
- HeroC
- ...

What I need this script to return is only the preceding part of the string, in this example **Monster** and **Hero**.

Comment: Post an example list, is it comma separated, newline separated?
Are they in order? Only one letter can be at the end of such strings?

Comment: Do you absolutely need a regex?  Otherwise word[:-1] will work

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need a regex:

```
re.match(r"(.*)[A-Z]", word).group(1)
```

But it is not the most efficient if you just want to remove the last character.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a *positive lookahead assertion* `(?=...)` to check the words ends in a single uppercase character and then use word boudaries `\b...\b` to ensure it does not match patterns that arent whole words:

```
>>> text = "This re will match MonsterA and HeroB but not heroC or MonsterCC"
>>> re.findall(r"\b[A-Z][a-z]+(?=[A-Z]\b)", text)
['Monster', 'Hero']
```

`re.findall` returns all such matches in a list.